# Change csound oscillator frequency while playing one note

Tags: unity-game-engine, csound

I'm using CSound in the context of **CSoundUnity** to build a synthesizer with Unity.
I would like to have the possibility to change the frequency of one note of quasi infinite duration during play-time. Not between notes.

The communication between the Unity C# script and csound is implemented via CSoundUnity "channels".

I implemented the oscillator in the csound-csd-file like this:

```
instr 1
 kfreq chnget "freq"
 iflg = p4
 asig oscils .7, kfreq, 0, iflg
 outs asig, asig
endin
```

This leads to a syntax error, because the parameter **kfreq** for the oscils-oscillator can only be changed **per note** and not during playing, so it cannot be a control parameter.

The script compiles in this form:

```
instr 1
 ifreq chnget "freq"
 iflg = p4
 asig oscils .7, ifreq, 0, iflg
 outs asig, asig
endin
```

but I want to have the possibility to change the frequency during playing.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The channel reading at k-rate is fine, you just need to use a different oscillator that accepts k-rate frequency changes. Try oscili or oscil3 for example.

Comment: Thank you! I probably will use **oscilikt**.